# PHP Get minimum value of a key in array of arrays

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'quantity' => 10),
    array('id' => 2, 'quantity' => 25),
    array('id' => 3, 'quantity' => 38),
    ...
);
```

I want to find the array contains minimum of quantity. How can I do it simply in one two lines of code?! (I prefer to use PHP functions)

Also if the variable is an Object, Does it make any difference?!

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
usort($array,function($a,$b) {return $a['quantity']-$b['quantity'];});
return $array[0];
```

If needed, create a copy of the original array using `$copy = array_slice($array,0);`

Answer (score -1):

For the min value:

```
$min = min(array_map("array_pop",$array));
print_r($min);
```

For the key:

```
$min = array_keys(array_map("array_pop",$array), min(array_map("array_pop",$array)));
print_r($min[0]);
```

Comment: Causes E_STRICT errors: only variables should be passed by reference (ie. to `array_pop`). Additionally, your code relies on an associative array being in a specific order.

Comment: @Kolink, aaahhhhh!!!!, I tried it on codepast only and initially seemed to work, we (I) never stop learning. Thanks for comment!